# Is it possible to resolve controller and service in ui-router resolve in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to resolve controller and service in ui-router reslove as follows

controller is :  'js/app/dashboard/dashboardService.js', 
 service is :     'js/app/dashboard/dashboard.Controller.js'

```
.state('dashboards.sample', {
             url: "/outlook",
             templateUrl: "views/Dashboard/sample.html",
             data: { pageTitle: 'Outlook view', specialClass: 'fixed-sidebar' },
             controller: 'productsController',
             controllerAs: 'pd',
             resolve: {

                 loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {

                     return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                         {
                             name: 'ProductModule',
                             files: ['js/app/dashboard/dashboardService.js', 'js/app/dashboard/dashboard.Controller.js']
                         }
                     ]);
                 }
             }
         })
```

The problem with this is controller is loaded before service (Sometimes it does the opposite). So is there a way to nested resolve this issue i.e first load the service than controller.

error usually thrown in console is

```
 angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ProductModule(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2015b @ angular.js:1939(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2013(anonymous function) @ dashboardService.js:2
angular.js:13236 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=dashboardServiceProvider%20%3C-NaNashboardService%20%3C-%20productsController
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:43:7
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:43:69
    at d (http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
    at e (http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:41:1)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:41:364)
    at http://localhost:8012/js/angular/angular.min.js:87:42
    at http://localhost:8012/js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by mentioning to load the files sequentially (i.e. `serie: true,`). By this way service file would be loaded before it is being used in controller.

```
.state('dashboards.sample', {
             url: "/outlook",
             templateUrl: "views/Dashboard/sample.html",
             data: { pageTitle: 'Outlook view', specialClass: 'fixed-sidebar' },
             controller: 'productsController',
             controllerAs: 'pd',
             resolve: {

                 loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {

                     return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                         {
                             serie: true,
                             name: 'ProductModule',
                             files: ['js/app/dashboard/dashboardService.js', 'js/app/dashboard/dashboard.Controller.js']
                         }
                     ]);
                 }
             }
         })
```